# Desktop wallpaper idea that's at the same time visual interesting and bland

Tags: images, desktop

I'm an IT guy rather than an artist of any kind. I work at a small college, and we're deploying new PCs to our classrooms.  As part of this, I want to build a desktop wallpaper to include with the machines by default, to help with branding for the college and the rollout and to create a consistent look across our classrooms.

Here's the kicker: many of our classrooms use smart boards, a kind of interactive whiteboard.  I need to come up with something that's both visually interesting enough to avoid looking empty and barren, but bare and light enough to still serve well as a white board, such that you can draw over it without the background taking away from the real content displayed above it. My color palette is essentially white and very light grey or yellow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coincidentally, someone posted a link to these [subtle patterns](http://subtlepatterns.com/) on the UX SE in response to quite a [different problem to do with backgrounds](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9223/how-to-prevent-grey-black-lines-after-effect). I think there's some good options for you there.

Comment: sweet. I'm gonna see if I can emboss the college seal into the brushed aluminum or leather pattern.

Comment: A fine, bookmark-worthy resource!

Comment: @Alan Gilbertson  true true, nice patterns!